# RE styling a link what does it mean 'styles links to visited pages?

Tags: css

Hi Regarding in CSS the code

```
a:link, a:visited { color: #38488f;
 text-decoration: none; }
```

I know that this styles a link but what on earth does it mean that 'visited means it styles links to visited pages'? I mean you have the link and of course most often users will click on the link and visit the webpage or another part of a site.

Comment: Have you searched your question before posting? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:visited

Answer (score 1):

When you click on an anchor then it's state is changed to visited that means that you have clicked on this anchor and have visited it, hence, in order to differentiate the visited links, you can add styles with help of this pseudo selector.

Comment: Hello janice4906. Anytime.

Answer (score 0):

link, targeting unvisited links, and visited, targeting, you guessed it, visited links, are the most basic pseudo classes.

The following will apply colors to all links in a page depending on whether the user has visited that page before or not:

```
a:link {
    color: blue;
}
a:visited {
    color: purple;
}
```

Comment: Hi Muhammed Athimannil Thanks for your enlightening reply. Regards janice4906

Comment: @janice4906 please accept the answer if you are satisfied with it